# Intent doesn't want to change from

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent

I got a problem here can you please help me? I'm lakgin this app about a quiz.
Now the first thing you see are categories this is the class:

```
package com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit.library.UserFunctions;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    Button btnEuropa;
    Button btnAmerika;
    Button btnAfrika;
    Button btnAzie;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Dashboard Screen for the application
         * */        
        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
            btnEuropa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEuropa);
            btnAmerika = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAmerika);
            btnAfrika = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAfrika);
            btnAzie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAzie);

            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    finish();
                }
            });
            btnEuropa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent start = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    start.putExtra("continent","europa");
                    start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(start);
                    finish();

                }
            });
            btnAmerika.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent start = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        start.putExtra("continent","amerika");
        start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(start);
        finish();

    }
});
btnAfrika.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent start = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        start.putExtra("continent","afrika");
        start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(start);
        finish();

    }
});
btnAzie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent start = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        start.putExtra("continent","azie");
        start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(start);
        finish();

    }
}); 


        }else{
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }




    }
}
```

When you first open the app and you click on the category for example: europe. You get all the questions about europe. When I change the category to Amerika you still get all the questions from europe. When I clear the data of my app it's over. If I then start with amerika i get the questions of america but if i change to europe i still get the questions from amerika.

This is the code in MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
         value = extras.getString("continent");
        }



        DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this, value);
```

And this is the code in DBHelper:

```
String continent;
    String input;
    public DBHelper(Context context, String input) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        continent = input;
    }
```

I then use is to get these:

```
if(continent.equals("europa")){
        .....
            }if(continent.equals("amerika")){
....}
```

Can u please help i'm stuck!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks fine from here.  It's possible the error is in the other activity.  Post the code for MainActivity.  I'm not sure, but a possibility is onRestoreInstanceState is restoring an old state.  I think Android creates a new instance, but maybe it's trying to be start and reusing old Activities.  onRestoreInstanceState gets called after onCreate.

Comment: I edited it with all the code

Comment: This also looks fine.  Have you set a breakpoint to make sure it's loading the correct questions from the database?

Comment: Yes I did all of that

Comment: Try adding a method that overrides onRestoreInstanceState.  All it should do is call the parent.  Look at the values of your controls before the parent method is called, and after.  If they change, then the culprit is onRestoreInstanceState.  I know this was a problem when the orientation changed.  I figure it's worth testing here.